# Writing Karma test for angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out how to write some simple Karma tests, but am having some trouble with syntax and just understanding the framework. Here is a controller that I want to write a test for:

```
myApp.controller('menuController', ['$rootScope', '$parse', '$attrs', '$scope', 'Menu', 'Track', '$state',
    function($rootScope, $parse, $attrs, $scope, Menu, Track, $state){
        $scope.Menu = Menu;
        $rootScope.$on("click",function() {
            Menu.active = false;
        });
        $scope.click = function(button) {
            Track.event(2, button + "_button_pressed", true);
        };
    }])
```

Here is a simple test I wrote for this controller, I am trying to test for the menu button's active status changing when it is clicked:

```
describe('Controller: menuController', function() {
    //load the module with menuController
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var MainCtrl,
        scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainCtrl = $controller('menuController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    //put test here
    it ('should change $scope.Menu.active to true when button is clicked', function() {
        expect(scope.Menu.active).toBeFalse();
        scope.click();
        expect(scope.Menu.active).toBeTrue();
    })


});
```

After running Grunt test, the test fails and one of the errors it returns is:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.Menu')
```

I was hoping if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me how to write a simple karma test for the controller shown above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing all of your dependencies on your `menuController` in your test. I would think that would be causing an error.

Comment: what dependencies would I need?

Comment: All of the ones listed in your main script. So `$rootScope, $parse, $attrs, $scope, Menu, Track, $state`

Comment: @AbhasArya - You don't need to explicitly define every dependency so long as your Karma config file pulls in all those files and they are all wired up to your `myApp` module.